# ASP.NET themes and static contents

Tags: asp.net, css, themes

as you all know, ASP.NET includes each CSS stylesheet in the App_Themes's Theme folder inside the page. No discussion.

But now, I'm facing a little problem having lots of CSS files in a theme and willing to use a [static content domain](http://www.ravelrumba.com/blog/static-cookieless-domain/). I would like to load all the static content of my website from the static domain (not only CSS, but also icons, images, etc.), but let's now pay attention only to CSS.

## My question is

Is it possible to override the behaviour of `Page` class, and for each CSS file found in Theme's folder, rewrite the `<link>` tag with the correct URL of the static content domain? I have nothing preventing me to deploy files into http://static.domain.com/App_Themes/Theme path, so at least adding a prefix to the tag is fine.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternate method is to write an http module.  Have the module inspect the html being sent back to the client.

If it detects a style sheet reference, change the location that the style sheet is pulling from.

This works for the other items as well, such as images etc.

Comment: Whoa!!! Seems we have a winner today!!! I thought about something like that (what I did in PHP to rewrite URLs) but I didn't think an HttpModule could inspect the outgoing HTML! What HttpApplication event should I hook to?

Comment: Problem end request.  You want to modify the html on the way out.  http://blog.tylerholmes.com/2008/09/httpmodules-your-best-friend.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.  You can have a custom base page class write the CSS files it finds in the folder.  Though, I'm not sure you can override the default behavior of the themes feature, so the easiest way is to move the CSS files outside of the default themes.  Then, you can use the System.IO objects to read the directory, access the file, and generate the link.

HTH.

Comment: Surely it's feasible as ad-hoc solution. But I don't know how difficult it is for maintaning *legacy* applications (as soon as they all have a common base Page class) that are widely based on themes that can be switched at runtime. I'll keep studyng ASP.NET's and Mono's code to find hints ;)

Comment: Surely, your solution is the **only** viable solution. By analysing the code of ASP.NET I found that many of the required classes/methods are internal. PageTheme class is an abstract class, but I found no way to override it, but **most important** its SetStyleSheet method is **internal**. Thanks for the help, anyway. I wanted to do something bigger and more scalable