# Manipulating HTTP Response

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, httpresponse

my current question is tightly related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594549/asp-net-themes-and-static-contents), but is far more specific. We have to plan a design strategy for the objective described in that question.

We want to do this by **rewriting HTML** on ASP.NET web forms. My question is: which strategy is the best according to parameters of **feasibility**, **performance impact** and **implementation effort on legacy applications**.

## What I have to do

is to basically get the HTML output of a Web Form, parse it, and replace certain URLs according to user-defined rules. In that example, I would rewrite all static content to CDN URLs, but it can be easily extended to URL rewriting techniques. I found **lots** (and I really mean **lots**) of articles about URL rewriting from the perspective of having URLs like `http://myblog.com/2092` interpreted as `http://myblog.com/Default.aspx?post=2092` but I found none showing me how to *smartly* format old-style URLs to shorter format right from inside HTML (so the page will render the short-form URL directly) [edit] without deep code intervention.

## Strategy 1

Like suggested in an answer of the above question, write an HTTP Module that intercepts the HTML and rewrites it. Actually, I looked around and saw I can set a `Response.Filter` stream object that performs the HTML filtering.

- Pros: I can inject the HTTP Module on a legacy application, configure rewriting rules via XML and have the oldest CRM/ecommerce application load static content from a CDN without touching its code **at all**.
- Cons: I suspected that (and a comment [here](http://aspnetlibrary.com/articledetails.aspx?article=Use-Response.Filter-to-intercept-your-HTML) confirms my suspects) having to reimplement a `Stream`'s `Write` method, which operates on a partial buffer in the general case, can result in bad replacements. Suppose the Write method is first called with a chunk like `ttp://mydomain.com/static/ima` (where I assume `<img src="h` was already written before) and later `ge.png" />` (so guess the final URL :-P) with a rewrite rule that regexes `http://mydomain.com/static/[^"]*` into `http://cdn.com/path/$1`, the substitution is not done. To workaround that, I could use a MemoryStream or something like that to **buffer** the complete set of data and then perform the substitutions, but it could cause troubles on highly loaded servers

## Strategy 2

Overriding `Page`'s `Render` method in a way such as described [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1049086.aspx)

- Pros: doesn't suffer the chunking problem
- Cons: requires defining a base class for all pages. Feasible on new applications, not sure for maintaining **legacy** applications. Seems has a problem as you cannot instantiate HttpTextWriter directly

Obviously, for the new webapps we'll have to develop, I would adopt strategy 2, but I really like using **dynamic components** a lot, as they can be plugged with ease when application requires them (so if our new app will be installed without a CDN the feature is turned off).

## Briefly, my questions are

How would you fix both strategies' cons (particularly 1st)? And, of course, do you have other strategies to suggest to achieve this objective?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to do this on the server side or the client side?

Comment: If you also have a client strategy, you are welcome. It could save some server computational effort. I asked for a server strategy, but 99% of my questions are made to **learn**, so any advice is welcome!!!! My doubt about client strategy (I guess it's a Javascript that parses HTML via DOM/JQuery/XPath/whatever) is that I *should* be sure that IMG urls are rewritten before the browser attempts to load them to get maximum performance. Anyway I'm curious about your strategy!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you could use ASP.NET's "adaptive control behavior" feature. See [Architectural Overview of Adaptive Control Behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67276kc5.aspx)

Basically you would redefine a new `HtmlTextWriter` class, associate it as the default renderer, and override "A" tag rendering with your own code.

Comment: Looking at that... Definitely awesome! I can also override the link and img tags to get the CDN rewriting. This method seems both pluggable as it needs only the .browser file in the main application AND not CPU-consuming since rewrite is done on the fly!! I'm beginning a couple of experiments... :)

Comment: I'm very interested in this technique. Can anyone direct me to a code sample? I'm specifically interested in rewriting image urls to use a different (CDN) subdomain.