# How to create SharePoint 2007 Web Application on a Virtual Path to solve an url rewrite rule?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, web-applications, url-rewriting, wss

I there anyway that I can install a SharePoint web application not on the root I need it on a virtual path? I have a situation that my customer is using somehow a url rewriting tool using ISA server like the following:
He have a main url let say http://publicsite/
we have sharepoint implemented internal on a site called http://internal/sites/sitecollection
when we open http://publicsite/sites/sitecollection it will open http://internal/sites/sitecollection
http://publicsite/ is on a different server than http://internal.
Right now I have an issue with the embedded resources in the rendered html markup for the sharepoint site like

```
<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=MZkmbKEwKTBSRdxFCFncmF72UDKBF9tO54OpDYX6Df4DBmB7HSDbA8CAqY5mCBAK2TAU34oVF24xOS5EJEafjb6Zcvwnmou5zv3RqxNzcSKM1XXzvQP1JpAzOAaH9PUPRTPUjZfdMBnoJPmBfgNZ-BFEntGwjcL7UiqfpH8R9TE1&amp;t=ffffffffed1cce36" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

effectually it opens from the root and root based on the customer rewrite rule is another server so the resource response with status 404
And AFAIN since the sharepoint web application on the root so I can't change the way it renders the url.

Is there any way to solve this?
I started to think about some javascript function to change the url of all scripts with starts with `/ScriptResource.axd` and change it to `/sites/sitecollection/ScriptResource.axd` but It faild to reload the javascript I don't know why!!
The 2nd solution Is to create the web application on a virtual path and I don't know if this possible or not, so can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance.
Regards

Comment: Are the servers hosting http://publicsite/ and http://interal/ part of the same SharePoint farm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first suggestion would be to create a different public url for sharepoint. You are going to save yourself a lot of hurt if you do.

But if you really need to go forward, you could try to implementing a HttpModule that replaces the bad references. And you are going to have to test this a fare bit it you are doing anything more than just viewing some content. (collaboration, office sync etc)

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5956/rich-text-editor-error-messages/8364#8364

Comment: Since the customer admits they wasn't follows Microsoft Best Practice as one-to-one mapping I will mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to change the path on the page. Changing the configuration of the ISA server will still leave you with the problem that the root is on a different server to the SharePoint site.

If the JavaScript approach did not work you could try use the "adaptive control behavior" as suggested as the answer for this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609336/manipulating-http-response), Where you rewrite all the Script tags, you will also need to rewrite the Style and Image tags as some will refer to /_layouts

A heavy handed approach though but Control adapters work well with SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking you could extend the web app on the internal server to the additional url http://publicsite/. Now you will rely on intelligent IP routing so that if the URL is http://publicsite/sites/sitecollection it goes to your intranet server, otherwise it goes to the public server. It sounds as though your ISA server already does this. I think that would make all the relative links correct.

Comment: The problem maybe from the customer isa server because it works like this: 
if the public url is: http://public/ renders http://internal/
if the public url us: http://public/blah renders http://internal/blah
and the two internal urls are on different servers. but sharepoint if u open any web application with any site and site collection depth it's always renders the scripts on the root /ScriptResource and when the browser renders the public page with /scriptresource on it it goes and get it from the server which applies to the 1st rule which it's not our sharepoint site!!